# Convert Raw to Wav Streams in NodeJS

Tags: c++, node.js, audio, portaudio

I am using a nodeJS library `naudio` —[link](https://github.com/Streampunk/naudiodon)— to record sound from a 2 microphones (total 4 channel audio with each microphone being stereo). This library spits out  a `.raw` file in the following specs: `16 BIT, 48000Hz Sample Rate, Channel Count 4`

```
// var portAudio = require('../index.js');
var portAudio = require('naudiodon');
var fs = require('fs');

//Create a new instance of Audio Input, which is a ReadableStream
var ai = new portAudio.AudioInput({
  channelCount: 4,
  sampleFormat: portAudio.SampleFormat16Bit,
  sampleRate: 48000,
  deviceId: 13
});

ai.on('error', console.error);

//Create a write stream to write out to a raw audio file
var ws = fs.createWriteStream('rawAudio_final.raw');

//Start streaming
ai.pipe(ws);
ai.start();

process.once('SIGINT', ai.quit);
```

Instead of the `.raw` file, I am trying to convert this to two individual `.wav` files. With the above encoding and information, what would be the best way to do so? I tried to dig around for easy ways to deinterleaving and getting `.wav` but seem to be hitting a wall.

Answer (score 6):

The addon is a wrapper around a C++ library called `portaudio` which according to its [documentation](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs-dev/write__wav_8c.html) supports writing to a `WAV` file.

What you could do is extend the addon and bind a `NodeJS` function to the underlying C++ function that write to `WAV`.
This will give you a good performance if it is an issue.

If you want something easier you could look up utilities that do the conversion and call them from within your script using `ex` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

Look similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059014/converting-raw-audio-data-to-wav-with-scripting).

You may also take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/asanoboy/3979747) to know how to create wav file from javascript.